How to Extract and Block VPN IP Addresses from NetworkManager Configuration Files Using iptables
I am seeking assistance with a script to manage VPN IP addresses in Linux NetworkManager.
Objective:
To extract IP addresses from VPN configuration files and block them using iptables.
Environment Details:

Location: /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
File type: .nmconnection
Target: VPN configuration files only

Current Attempt:
ip=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}'  /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*)

iptables -A INPUT -s "$ip"  -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -d "$ip" -j DROP

Issues to Resolve:

Need to identify and process only VPN configuration files
Extract individual IP addresses (Example: 137.119.23.205)
Apply iptables rules for each IP separately

Specific Questions:

What is the recommended method to filter VPN configuration files?
How can IP addresses be extracted individually?
What is the correct approach to iterate through and block each IP?

Technical Requirements:

Solution must be implemented in Bash
Must handle multiple files
Must process only valid IP addresses

I would appreciate guidance on implementing this functionality correctly and efficiently.

Note: I have appropriate permissions to access these system files and modify iptables rules.
++ grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' '/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Auto WIND_2.4G_528BA2.nmconnection' '/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Ethernet connection 1.nmconnection' /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/.....tcp.nmconnection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/........tcp.nmconnection
+ ip='/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/.......tcp.nmconnection:93.190.140.103
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/........tcp.nmconnection:87.249.134.133
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/...........tcp.nmconnection:87.249.134.133
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/...........tcp.nmconnection:87.249.134.133'
+ iptables -A INPUT -s '/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/.........tcp.nmconnection:93.190.140.103
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/.........tcp.nmconnection:87.249.134.133
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/......tcp.nmconnection:87.249.134.133
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/.......tcp.nmconnection:87.249.134.133' -j DROP
iptables v1.8.9 (nf_tables): Hostname too long
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.


Are these IPv4 or IPv6 addresses?

What exactly are you struggling with? Reading multiple files? Getting IP addresses from multiple filesß

I'd try to use nmcli for that.

@Dimitar IPv4 adress. Maybe in the future I want IPv6 too, but at the moment I want IPv4. Thank you

@NicoHaase I want because I put those ip in app that use iptables. My goal is to extract those IP then to DROP them for some users with iptables.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section. Also, if you tried anything, share the attempts

@NicoHaase Just flag it as lacking details or clarity.

@Dimitar that's what I did way before you gave that advice

"I didn't solve it" - why not? What happens instead? Can you share sample input data?

@NicoHaase iptables v1.8.9 (nf_tables): Hostname too long

@NicoHaase : Hostname too longthis command export all directory so iptables cannot work ./etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/xxxxxxxxx.tcp.nmconnection

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it - sounds like you should check whatever $ip contains

@NicoHaase I did it. Please check it.

You still haven't shared any information about the input files - even if they might contain standard stuff (like a lot of other systems), seeing them might help others to craft the proper commands. Unless you share such details, we can only guess about which parts to extract

@NicoHaase which is input files? I don't understsand. Tell me which files are you want then I share them.

You wrote in the question "To extract IP addresses from VPN configuration files" - how should we know how these files look like if you don't share them?

I would suggest using a regex in combination with another command such as grep or awk to accomplish this task.
Here is an example using regex, assuming IPv4 format:
grep -oE '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' vpn.log > extracted_ips


As I said a friend above My goal is to extract those IP then to DROP them for some users with iptables. So with your example won't help.

@user21379959 should have mentioned that in the question so as to not waste anybody's time.

I updated. I didn do wth deceit.
